# PHP preg_replace removing text from symbol to something symbol

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

i will to try from my data, data is :

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##samtoolsVersion=0.1.19-44428cd
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Raw read depth">
#CHROM/home/bioinf/jobs/41/sorting/output.bam
aaa bbb ccc dddd
eee fff ggg hhhh
```

I want to get the data into :

```
aaa bbb ccc dddd
eee fff ggg hhhh
```

I dont know how to remove them using preg_replace syntax.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any attempts to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$data = preg_replace('/#.*?\n/s', '', $data);
```

This would also work:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$newArr = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!empty($line[0]) && $line[0] !== '#') {
        $newArr[] = $line;
    }
}
$data = implode("\n", $newArr);
```